# SQL Server query explanation - comma separated values into separate row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I found the great way how to get values from one row, which are separated by comma into separate row:

```
SELECT 
    q2.value  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Data, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS thexml   
     FROM
         MyTable) q1  
CROSS APPLY  
    (SELECT 
         x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS value 
     FROM 
         thexml.nodes('x') AS f(x)) q2
```

But there is confusing part, hopefully someone can explain it a bit:

```
(SELECT 
     x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS value 
 FROM 
     thexml.nodes('x') AS f(x)) q2
```

Comment: What are you confused about, specifically? btw, for SQL Server 2016 or higher, there is a built in string_split function.

Answer (score 0):

q1 is a derived table with a single column thexml of XML type with one row per row from MyTable.

q1.thexml, after the replace and cast operations, holds all of the previously comma-separated values from MyTable.Data as a simple flat sequence of x elements - each one holds one of the original comma-separated values.

The nodes method call simply returns a single column table with one row per x element (i.e. thus one row per original comma-separated value)

Note that the query written as it is will not behave as expected if you have any XML characters in your source data and performance might be an issue with larger data sets.

In SQL Server 2016, the function STRING_SPLIT has been introduced. This will return a single column table from a string of separated (e.g. by comma) values.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

The part of the query which you mention `(SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)') as value FROM thexml.nodes('x') as f(x)) q2`, is based on xml Data Type Methods.

this part `x.value('.','varchar(100)')` of the query is based on the Method value() of XML Data Type ([you can read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)), and using XQuery expression in order to retrieves data inside the XML instance.

This part `thexml.nodes('x')` uses the value of thexml and parse it internally using the method nodes(). [You can read more in this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017).